# Why can't I have an absolute import (using create-react-app + typescript) in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I'm getting started on a project using the react template for a .NET Core MVC WebApp and I'm having some trouble with absolute imports. As far as I understand it, I can set `baseUrl` in my .tsconfig and that should be the end of it. While this works like a charm in VS Code I cannot seem to get it working in VS 2019.

Here is my basic file/folder structure:

```
--src
  --Context
    Context.ts
  --App
    App.tsx
```

When I try `import * as Context from 'Context/Context'` from `App.tsx`:

VS2019 gives me the following error:
`(TS) Cannot find module` 
[image]

However, when I open up the same project/files in VS Code it works as expected.

[image]

Could someone please explain to me how I can get the behaviour of VS Code in VS2019 and/or why VS2019 doesn't work the way I'm expecting it to?

Comment: Years ago when VS code first came out I used VS for everything. I found when I tried to build UI projects in VS it was a problem. VS code makes things way easier. Is there a specific reason why you would want to use VS over code?

Comment: I'm migrating an existing project built using old versions of .net and react which has a large amount of backend code that vastly outweighs the frontend. Besides, it's not really my decision, it's a work project and this is what the dev team is using.

Comment: What's stopping you from working on the UI in VS code and ignoring the issue in VS? At the end of the day it's just a folder structure and you could edit it in notepad if you wanted to.

Comment: I guess nothing other than the additional complexity, it seems a bit of a pain to need multiple IDEs to work on one project, as well as I don't really like the idea of just ignoring the issue in VS.

Comment: I feel your pain. I've worked on .Net projects for years and it's just become natural to work on C# code in VS and JS in VS code. I think of VS as my .Net compiler whereas VS code is my JS compiler. Hopefully you'll get a good answer to your problem.

Comment: @Mickers Just in case you were interested, I think I found a solution to the issue

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find what I think to be the solution to this issue. I've been looking through the settings for both VS 2019 and VS Code to see if I could find any blatant mismatches and I came across a setting for `Module Specifier Preference` [VS 2019] / `Import Module Specifier` [VS Code] that had very similar options.

In VS Code this was set to "Auto" however in VS 2019 it was set to "Always use relative paths".

I updated this in VS 2019 to "Automatically determine best import path", restarted VS and voila! I'm now able to use absolute path imports for my typescript files.

Since changing this setting I still get IntelliSense errors in the error list window about not being able to find a module when using an absolute import path but this doesn't appear in the editor and I'm able to successfully build and deploy.

## The Solution

Go to `Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Formatting > General`. Set `Module Specifier Preference (TS 2.9 or later)` to `Automatically determine best import path`. Lastly `Restart Visual Studio`

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution to your issue.